# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on openwrt

Tags: ros, linux, embedded

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is anyone working on ROS in OpenWRT? (I know it's been asked before, but back in 2012....)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221473/ros-on-openwrt/) by [btsimonh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25169/btsimonh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not a commonly used platform. In theory it should work fine for lower computational tasks. I believe that you will need to compile from source and manually resolve system dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0